# Component v for doesn't recognise prop, if not explicitly declared while initializing object in root

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

In my root, I am declaring my (multidimensinal) object in data like so:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
       accounts: {}
}
```

If I send the props like this:

```
<div id="root">
   <my-component :accounts="accounts"></my-component>
</div>
```

Also in component, accept props. In the component, I also have the template that I perform a for loop.

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
   props: ['accounts'],
   template `
       <div>
        <another-component v-for="(x, i) in accounts"></another-component>
       </div>
   `
})
```

In this case, where while I am initializing the accounts in the root, if I give it an empty object, it won't perform the loop.

If in for loop, instead of accounts, I use a digit, it performs the loop.

Also, while initializing in the root, if I become explicit...

```
accountTypes : {
     1: [],
     2: []
},
```

...the for loop works. However, this time I get another error:

> Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.

Also, I don't want to be explicit on 1 and 2, sometimes I don't want 2 to be there at all.

---

I am filling up accounts with a method in my root, binded to checkbox `@change`.

```
 methods: {
   accountSelected() {
       this.pushValue(index, name)
   },

   pushValue(key, value) {
        var obj = this.accounts

        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var idx = $.inArray(value, obj[key]);
            if (idx == -1) {
                obj[key].push(value);
            }
        } else {
            obj[key] = [value];
        }
    },
 }
```

Comment: If you dynamically add a property to an object, Vue will not be able to detect it was added and it will not be reactive. You need to add it using $set. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: How can I use $set with nested objects like this one? Can you please show an example. Do I need to declare a object push and object delete methods?

Comment: Where/when are you adding to accounts?

Comment: Using `@change="accountSelected"` on checkboxes, I use the pushValue method which I added in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, [Vue cannot detect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) when you add properties to an object after that object has been added to the Vue. Use [$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) in your `else` clause.

```
pushValue(key, value) {
    var obj = this.accountTypes

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var idx = $.inArray(value, obj[key]);
        if (idx == -1) {
            obj[key].push(value);
        }
    } else {
        this.$set(obj, key, [value]);
    }
},
```

The error you are seeing with respect to a `key` is likely because you are setting a `key` during your loop:

```
<another-component v-for="(x, i) in accounts" :key="x"></another-component>
```

The problem here is that `x` is an *array*. `i`, however is just the key of `accounts`, so use that.

```
<another-component v-for="(x, i) in accounts" :key="i"></another-component>
```

Comment: It worked however I got the same error 'Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.'

Comment: @senty where are you using a key?